# BigNumber.js simple subtraction giving wrong output

Tags: javascript, bigint, decimal.js

I have used Bignumber.js API for performing some JS calculations involving large numbers. I am performing a subtraction where the result should be `0` but the output is like `-0.00000000000000000099`. How do I counter such issues with Bignumber API.

```
(new BigNumber(refinedGoal)).minus(monthlyReminder).toFixed()
```

gives `-0.00000000000000000099`

while using arithmetic subtraction operator

```
((new BigNumber(refinedGoal)) - monthlyReminder).toFixed()
```

gives `0`.
My overall goal is to save this result `0` in some JSON variable.

Edit 1:
The `monthlyReminder.toFixed()` value is `1030.19999999999999999886`
and `refinedGoal` value is `1030.2`

Comment: What are the values of `refinedGoal` and `monthlyReminder` when you get that result? Because `(new BigNumber(0.5)).minus(0.2).toFixed()` is returning `0.3` as expected.

Comment: Have you defined `refinedGoal` and `monthlyReminder` by specifying type `number` to `BigNumber` constructor? If yes specify them in `string` type instead of `number` to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: @sgarza62 I have added the respective values in the question.

Comment: @adzo261 yes `monthlyReminder` is a Bignumber object while `refinedGoal` is a JS native number

Comment: Try defining your variables in string for e.g: `new BigNumber('1119.234')` or if you want from a variable which is a javascript number then - `new BigNumber(variable.toString())`.